# Change a href url on page load

Tags: jquery

Is there a quick and easy way to change/overwrite a `href` url sturcture on page load?

The HTML structure is very basic:

**Code:**

```
<ul class="sub_menu" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <li><a href="value">someLink</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: overwrite with which value?

Comment: change href value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it works

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('a[href*="value"]').attr('href' , 'your url');
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('ul.sub_menu li a[href=value]').attr('href' , 'your url');
});
```

Comment: How could I make it specific to `sub_menu `?

Comment: i have add sub_menu specific in above answer

Answer (score 1):

you can like this.

```js
$(window).load(function(){
$('ul li a').attr('href','http://stackoverflow.com/');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="https://www.google.com.ph" target="_blank">links</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

**In jQuery, you can use :**

```
$('.sub_menu a[href="old_href"]').prop('href', 'newhref...');
```

[JQUERY DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/amj0bhzh/)

**In pure javascript :**

```
var menu_ob = document.getElementsByClassName('sub_menu')[0];
var element = menu_ob.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
    if (element[i].href == 'https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/value') {
        element[i].href = 'newhref';
    }
}
```

[JAVASCRIPT DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/amj0bhzh/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Is more specific with `sub_menu >li> a[href=value]`

```js
(function (){
  console.log('before:'+$('.sub_menu  li a').attr('href'))
  $('.sub_menu  li a[href=value]').attr('href','http://example.com');
  console.log('current_one:'+$('.sub_menu  li a').attr('href'))
  })()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sub_menu" >
    <li><a href="value">someLink</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks,  Could I some how do a where statement so it changes  where the current one is?